# Wordpress - hide childrens of subpages in wp_list pages

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have following page structure:

- Main page (id 5)

  - Subpage 1

    - children page
    - children page
  - Subpage 2

    - children page
    - children page

I use this code for displaying my sidebar menu:

```
 <?php wp_list_pages('child_of=5&title_li=&link_before=<span>&link_after=</span>'); ?>
```

This code displays only a list. I would need to display

- when on the main page, display only subpages
- when on the subpage, display subpages and children pages of the subpage I'm currently on
- when on the children page, display the display subpages and children pages of the parent subpage I'm currently on

Any idea how to do this?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working code, works like a charm for me:

```
/**
 * Create HTML list of pages.
 *
 * @package Razorback
 * @subpackage Walker
 * @author Michael Fields <michael@mfields.org>
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010, Michael Fields
 * @license http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License
 *
 * @uses Walker_Page
 *
 * @since 2010-05-28
 * @alter 2010-10-09
 */
class Razorback_Walker_Page_Selective_Children extends Walker_Page {
    /**
     * Walk the Page Tree.
     *
     * @global stdClass WordPress post object.
     * @uses Walker_Page::$db_fields
     * @uses Walker_Page::display_element()
     *
     * @since 2010-05-28
     * @alter 2010-10-09
     */
    function walk( $elements, $max_depth ) {
        global $post;
        $args = array_slice( func_get_args(), 2 );
        $output = '';

        /* invalid parameter */
        if ( $max_depth < -1 ) {
            return $output;
        }

        /* Nothing to walk */
        if ( empty( $elements ) ) {
            return $output;
        }

        /* Set up variables. */
        $top_level_elements = array();
        $children_elements  = array();
        $parent_field = $this->db_fields['parent'];
        $child_of = ( isset( $args[0]['child_of'] ) ) ? (int) $args[0]['child_of'] : 0;

        /* Loop elements */
        foreach ( (array) $elements as $e ) {
            $parent_id = $e->$parent_field;
            if ( isset( $parent_id ) ) {
                /* Top level pages. */
                if( $child_of === $parent_id ) {
                    $top_level_elements[] = $e;
                }
                /* Only display children of the current hierarchy. */
                else if (
                    ( isset( $post->ID ) && $parent_id == $post->ID ) ||
                    ( isset( $post->post_parent ) && $parent_id == $post->post_parent ) ||
                    ( isset( $post->ancestors ) && in_array( $parent_id, (array) $post->ancestors ) )
                ) {
                    $children_elements[ $e->$parent_field ][] = $e;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Define output. */
        foreach ( $top_level_elements as $e ) {
            $this->display_element( $e, $children_elements, $max_depth, 0, $args, $output );
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Depth to handle what you want it to show

```
<?php wp_list_pages('child_of=5&depth=1&title_li=&link_before=<span>&link_after=</span>'); ?>
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

> The default value is 0 (display all pages, including all sub-pages).
>
> ```
>     0 (default) Displays pages at any depth and arranges them hierarchically in nested lists
>     -1 Displays pages at any depth and arranges them in a single, flat list
>     1 Displays top-level Pages only
>     2, 3 … Displays Pages to the given depth
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but depth doesn't allow me to selectively display the children pages, it displays them all, right? I mean, I won't be able to do `when on the subpage, display subpages and only children pages of the subpage I'm currently on`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this [Hierarchical Pages Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hierarchical-pages/). I'm not sure if it supports exactly what you want, but I used it on one of my projects and it worked great.

This widget will:

> Make collapsing hierarchical pages/category/taxonomy lists: top
>   level; ancestors, children, and/or siblings of current